# Synonym request: [vpn] to [networking]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I think [vpn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) should be a synonym of [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) - VPN questions are largely going to be off topic on Arqade so having it's own dedicated tag is a bit overkill, and VPN questions will always be networking related.

Comment: If VPN questions are off-topic then a merge is in order but not the synonym -- the tag should die to discourage any more off-topic posts.  I agree with Wipqozn, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's true that all [vpn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) questions will be related to networking, the reverse is (obviously) not true. Having the [vpn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) tag makes it easier for users looking for questions related just to [vpn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) to find said questions.

I also don't think we should be deleting tags just because there will only be a few questions where that tag is relevant. A tag with only a few questions may be an indication the tag has other problems which may make it worthy of deletion, but I don't see that as a problem within it of itself.

Plus we have enough questions tagged with [vpn](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vpn) that it won't be deleted automatically, so there's no concern with the tag being removed and leaving us with untagged questions.

Comment: What is the threshold of 'enough questions tagged that it won't be deleted automatically'?

Comment: @pixel A tag with only 1 question will automatically be deleted after a certain period. I believe it's 6 months.

Comment: there is only one valid question on that tag, can we synonym to networking now? :)

Comment: I have a feeling that most VPN questions will be tagged with the VPN program that's being used (e.g. Hamachi).